# Displaying data from firestore into HTML table

Tags: javascript, firebase, html-table, google-cloud-firestore

I need to display the data of my exercises collection into an HTML table.
I thought of getting it done by using getElementByID but it is displaying only 1 row. What is the proper way of doing this? Thank You.

Please see codes below:

**HTML code**

```
<div class="container">
              <h2>Manage Exercises:</h2>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Exercise Name</th>
                        <th>Body Part</th>
                        <th>Exercise Type</th>
                        <th>Sets + Reps/Duration</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="tr">
                        <td id="ename"></td>
                        <td id="body_part"></td>
                        <td id="etype"></td>
                        <td id="esets"></td>
                        <td id="eimage"></td>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
```

**Javscript code:**

```
console.log("Initialisation Successful!");
var db = firebase.firestore();

var exRef = db.collection('Exercises');
var allex = exRef
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        var EName = doc.data().Name;
        var Type = doc.data().Type;
        var BodyPart = doc.data(). BodyPart;
        var Sets = doc.data().Sets;
        const Image = doc.data().Image;

        document.getElementById("ename").value = EName;   
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

**Update:**

Replaced:  `document.getElementById("ename").value = EName;`

By:        `document.getElementById("ename").innerText = EName;`

It is now displaying one record only, how can I display all of them?

Comment: Only form controls like `<input>` have `value` property

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to try something more like this using the [innerText](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) property on the element:

```
document.getElementById("ename").innerText = EName;
```

Comment: Hey that helped, but instead I used : document.getElementById("ename").innerHTML = EName; from the innerText property link. But it is displaying one data only.

Comment: innerText is better than innerHTML for Rae data. You're adding text, not html.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried these code and it works for me. I did not code based on your case, but your case is similar to mine. I hope it helps!

**HTML Code**

```
<h3>ACTIVE USER</h3>

        <table id="tbl_account_list" border="2" cellpadding="10" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <thead>
                <th>EMAIL</th>
                <th>FULL_NAME</th>
                <th>UNI_ID</th>
            </thead>

        </table>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
firestore.collection('account').get().then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                    renderAccount(doc);
                })
            })

            const accountList = document.querySelector('#tbl_account_list') ;
            function renderAccount(doc){
                let tr = document.createElement('tr');
                let td_email = document.createElement('td');
                let td_full_name = document.createElement('td');
                let td_uni_id = document.createElement('td');

                tr.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
                td_email.textContent = doc.data().email;
                td_full_name.textContent = doc.data().full_name;
                td_uni_id.textContent = doc.data().uni_id;

                tr.appendChild(td_email);
                tr.appendChild(td_full_name);
                tr.appendChild(td_uni_id);

                accountList.appendChild(tr);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append text in dom element like this:

```
document.getElementById("ename").value += EName
```